# JavaScript what does the uneval function do?

Tags: javascript, eval

> **NOTE:** I do realize that there's currently low browser support for the
>   `uneval` function, however I am in interest to know what it does, and how it works.

I know that `eval()` executes javascript code as a string, but `uneval()` seems strange to me. It appears that it *unevaluates* code, judging by one of its uses, **deep** *object cloning.* For example:

```
let myObject = {  nonsense: null  };
var newObject = eval(  uneval(myObject)  ); 
// The above example deeply clones myObject in Mozilla Firefox
```

But how does the magic work just like that? What does `uneval` do, that allows such uses? More importantly, what could the other uses be? As it seamlessly **unevaluated** *evaluated content;* the real test is, can it *unevaluate* anything else *besides content passed through the `eval()` function (Or in this particular case, vice versa)?*

Comment: I highly suggest taking a few minutes to read the documentation on a subject before asking questions like this here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/uneval

Comment: I am aware of the support incapabilities, I just find it hard to understand the concept.

Comment: @MarkB I find you're tough: clearly the OP _did_ read documentation, but he's wondering how and for what kind of job this function might be useful. I didn't even noticed it existed, and I wonder too. The only usage I can think to at the moment is something like outputting a variable content representation without using console...

Comment: From the doc linked above: *"The uneval() function creates a string representation of the source code of an Object."*. What is not clear about that? Seems to be a bit like JSON.Stringify, but not just for the data, but for the source of an object. The name 'uneval' is a bit odd, though.. It's not exactly the opposite of eval.

Comment: @GolezTRol I understand your concern, I just found it confusing and hard to grasp, but now I understand after carefully reading the doc and by reading the answers/comments.

Comment: @cFreed if he had read the documentation he wouldn't be asking "can it unevaluate anything else besides content passed through the eval() function". That was the core question he was asking, and that is clearly answered by reading the documentation.

Comment: @MarkB Reading the last OP's comment, I recognize you're right! That's said, personally I keep wondering which is the utility of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `uneval` function returns the source of a given object; whereas the `eval` function does the opposite, by evaluating that source code. *Think of it this way*, you get the source of an object, then you evaluate the source to get the same object, just in a different memory area. Here's a link to a good resource on the mom documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/uneval, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Boom! That's it. This analogy helps me grasp the logic behind `uneval`. Also, I found it kind of similar to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))` after reading @GolezTRol's comment.

Comment: Correct, you can say that the JSON functions help complete the analogy just as well.